# Three.js Tube Geometry based on a custom geometry

Tags: javascript, jsp, 3d, three.js, webgl

I've got a set of lines as vectors like:

```
line1: [10,10,9,10,10]
line2: [10,9,8,10,10]
line3: [10,10,10,10,10]
```

each value of which represents the measure of the diameter of a tube (of nominal diameter 10) at different heights in the tube, with each line the diameter at a different rotation. That is:

- line1 is the diameter of the tube at 0 degrees,
- line2 is the diameter of the tube at 15 degrees,
- line3 is the diameter of the tube at 65 degrees

The number of lines and their rotations can vary, but I want to visualise these lines as a tube (well, a tube of partial measurements) in 3D using Three.js.

Am I best trying to create a custom geometry using as many lines as I have to create it, or can I use the TubeGeometry to attach my lines onto? Is it possible to create a tube based on these lines with values between the lines extrapolated?

The end result I'm trying to achieve is a 3D mesh that I can zoom in and out of.

Any thoughts or suggestions are most welcome!

Comment: Create a `CylinderGeometry` and then assign the vertices new locations. If you are having trouble, show what you have tried with a simple live example, and ask a specific question.

Comment: Hi, I've got a simple cylinder with: 

    `var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 50, 50, 200, 25,25,false );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ee00, wireframe: true, transparent: true } ); 
    tube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    tube.position.y = 425;   
    scene.add( tube ); `

but I'm not sure how to add new vertices to it. I was thinking that I could just add a set of vectors as vertices, like:

`var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);`

but I can't seem to find an example of how I attach these to the 'tube' object

Comment: Do not 'add' vertices, 'move' the vertices of the geometry. If that is too hard for you at this point, forget the cylinder for now, and just render the lines in 3D using `THREE.Line()`. Then to make it easy, view the scene by moving the camera with `TrackballControls`, not by rotating the lines.